# How to add loading image using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i want to add a loading or spinner message  until the form/server has finished reloading how do i check and know  that form has finished loading to disable the spinner?

NOTE: once the form is submitted the updated data  is not available until the server restart only the form heading is visible, while the restart and changes are updated. Currently i am manually refreshing the page until form is available again.

here is my  html and jquery snippet and loading code . My loading code is not working.

Code for loading message

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
              $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>')
                .insertBefore('#myform')
                .ajaxStart(function() {
                  $(this).show();
                }).ajaxStop(function() {
                  $(this).hide();
                });
            });
```

Comment: unless there's a really good reason not to, I recommend using jQuery's validate plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation). You'll be able to submit via ajax, display errors, spinner, etc. easily.

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest solution for the loading image, you can use the jquery plugin [prettyLoader](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyloader/).

You then only need to initialize the plugin once the DOM is loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.prettyLoader();
    });
</script>
```

And then it will display a loading Icon whenever an ajax request is made, automatically.

Updating the table can be done in two ways: Either you load the HTML in the ajax request and simply overwrite it:

```
$('#myTable').innerHtml = data;
```

Or you can return a json-object with the table data and put this data into the table. For that, I would recommend you use some kind of a Viewmodel, for example [Knockout.js](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/).

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to your script :

```
// to show the loading spinner

$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
    $('#loader').show();
});

// to hide the loading spinner

$("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
    $('#loader').hide();
});
```

loader will be your div with absolute positioned div element with 100% of width and height with a loading gif in the center (if you want or that could be just a text message of loading please wait... like this)

Comment: Thanks.. how would i know that my form has finished loading so i can hide the image after the form completes loading?

Comment: There is nothing to do when your ajax request stops then your spinner will be get hide by the .ajaxStop() function. yeah this will do.

Comment: I added that it didnt seem to display the loading